# Does the version in Socket-IO Library matters?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a Project which is Using Socket-io library for WebSocket Implementation. So, basically the library that my server is using and the library that I have used in Front-End both have different versions. So, I am confused that is it fine or I should use the same version for both. Also, which one is Appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the same version on both sides. You can review the migration section of the socket.io docs with the breaking changes from version to version. See links below:

[2.x -> 3.0](https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/)

[3.x -> 4.0](https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/)

Comment: I have used Flask for Making a Server and I am using React as a Front-End Framework. So, is that gonna make any difference to your Answer?

Comment: Socket.io initially started out as a javascript library and I have actually used flask too as a back-end server myself. Versioning may be off when you have a library used for different languages. Either way, I am sure you have read the relevant information about the client/server compatibility.